# Calculate similarity/distance between rows using pandas faster

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am fairly new to Python and Pandas.
I have following columns in a Pandas Datframe:

SongNumber  songID  albumID artistID    similarArtists  artistHotttnesss    songHotness loudness    tempo   year

With numerical data from artistHotnesss to year columns.
So I tried calculating distance/cosine between songs using the below code:

```
t1=time()
m = 1000
mat = np.zeros((m, m))

for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(0,m):
        if i != j:
            mat[i][j] = euclidean(data.ix[i,5:], data.ix[j,5:])
            '''if data.ix[i,2] == data.ix[j,2]:
                mat[i][j] += 1
            if data.ix[i,3] == data.ix[j,3]:
                mat[i][j] += 1
            #l1,l2 - list of similar artists
            l1_str = data.ix[i,4].strip(']')[1:]
            l2_str = data.ix[j,4].strip(']')[1:]
            l1 = l1_str.split()
            l2 = l2_str.split()
            common  = len(set(l1).intersection(l2))
            mat[i][j] += common
            mat[i][j] /= 3'''
        else:
            mat[i][j] = 0.0
t2 =time()
print(t2-t1)
```

So this essentially requires looping 10^4*10^4 times.
If I perform this for m =1000 , I get results in 2249 sec or 37.48 mins, so I am not getting the results for m = 10000 in time.

How can I speed it up (by avoiding loops ? pandas functions) ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid using loops by using the `euclidean_distances` function in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html).

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
import numpy as np

mat = np.random.rand(5, 5)
pairwise_dist_mat = euclidean_distances(mat)
pairwise_dist_mat
array([[ 0.        ,  1.19602663,  1.08341967,  1.07792121,  1.1245057 ],
   [ 1.19602663,  0.        ,  0.52135682,  0.82797734,  0.78247091],
   [ 1.08341967,  0.52135682,  0.        ,  0.87764513,  0.81903634],
   [ 1.07792121,  0.82797734,  0.87764513,  0.        ,  0.1386294 ],
   [ 1.1245057 ,  0.78247091,  0.81903634,  0.1386294 ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Can you prove using `sklearn` is faster than using `numpy` and `for` loops?

Comment: because it uses linear algebra as opposed to for loops to calculate distances. from the documentation, the formula is dist(x, y) = sqrt(dot(x, x) - 2 * dot(x, y) + dot(y, y)) (where dot is the dot product)

Comment: you can make your own vectorized function with numpy if you want, but there is no way that for loops will be faster

Comment: you can also use `pdist` in scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist

Comment: In my experiences, `sklearn` is slow and calculating distance measures straightforwardly with `numpy` outperforms it.

Comment: there is absolutely no way that having nested for loops is faster than matrix algebra. if the OP wants to use scipy or write their own numpy vectorized function, they can do so, but the original method posted will always be slower

Comment: @dmb : It performed incredibly fast for me , I think its using matrix algebra  as well as parallelization for operation on matrices.

Comment: @dmb : But will I need to traverse data frame(n*n)  if I want to use my own distance measure or there is faster way to do this too ?
(Made an commented edit to code  to highlight my situation of own distance measure).